# Create database tables from html tables

Tags: html, postgresql, html-table, database-table

I need help creating database tables from html tables. Right now I'm just manually doing it.
I have a html doc that has all the data but I don't know what the best way to extract the data.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ATOMS Definition for Type tom.service.soc.SocRecord</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 45px;
}
#box-table-a
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#box-table-a th
{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe;
    border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
}
#box-table-a td
{
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e8edff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#box-table-a tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0dafd;
    color: #339;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table id="box-table-a" summary="Definition for tom.service.soc.SocRecord">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">tom.service.soc.SocRecord</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Version</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>[type is UNCLASSIFIED] Temporary dummy test object for SOC</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="box-table-a" summary="Fields Definition for Type tom.service.soc.SocRecord">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Index</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Range</th>
            <th scope="col">Default</th>
            <th scope="col" width="50%">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>socID</td>
            <td>String</td>
            <td>           
-
            </td>
            <td>""</td>
            <td>
                [ ] The UUID of the tracked object -- String for transmission purposes  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>satID</td>
            <td><a href="../../../../../tom/state/vcm/SatNumberType.html">SatNumberType</a></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                [ ] The ID of the tracked object -- copy of the satelliteId in the VCM  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Here is the html.
I would like help making a create postgres database table script like this from the html. And if it has a href then that links to another table.

```
CREATE TABLE soc.SocRecord( 
    socId TEXT, --[ ] The UUID of the tracked object -- String for transmission purposes
    satId UUID, --[ ] The ID of the tracked object -- copy of the satId in the VCM
    commonName TEXT, --[ ] The name of the tracked object -- may be blank - 
                     --This field is optional in the current version of the message, check the set attribute before use.);
```

Comment: afaik, there is no way to parse html directly and put it into sql. you will need a general purpose programming language (e.g. javascript, python, .net, java, etc) equipped with html parsing library to parse the html and then put the data into database using ORM or something.

Comment: also, you could pay people to do menial works.. just saying. we are not free code generator, show us what have you tried and where did you stuck in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
Tried out some more variants and found that using `zip` resulted in no errors and returned the sql script.

> for header, value in **zip**(headers, values):

I've updated the code bellow as well.

---

So your approach could constitute something like:

read `.html` file
parse for `table`
parse for `theader` and so on

I find idea pretty interesting, so I tried it out in python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the path to your HTML file
html_file_path = 'path/to/your/file.html'
```

here you could write another script to read all `.html` files in a folder and execute against that instead.

```
# Read the contents of the HTML file
with open(html_file_path, 'r') as file:
    html = file.read()

# Find all the tables in the HTML
tables = soup.find_all('table')

# Iterate over the tables
for table in tables:
    # Find the table's ID attribute
    table_id = table.get('id')

    # Extract the table headers
    headers = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('thead').find_all('th')]

    # Create a dictionary to store the table data
    table_data = {}

    # Iterate over the table rows
    for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        # Extract the row cells
        cells = row.find_all('td')

        # Extract the cell values
        values = [cell.get_text().strip() for cell in cells]

        # Store the values with their corresponding headers in the dictionary
        for header, value in zip(headers, values):
            if header not in table_data:
                table_data[header] = []
            table_data[header].append(value)

    # Generate the PostgreSQL table script
    create_table_script = f"CREATE TABLE {table_id} (\n"
    for header, values in table_data.items():
        # Handle column names with spaces or special characters
        column_name = header.lower().replace(' ', '_').replace('.', '_')

        # Combine the column values into a comma-separated string
        column_values = ', '.join([f"'{value}'" if isinstance(value, str) else str(value) for value in values])

        # Append the column definition to the script
        create_table_script += f"    {column_name} {column_values},\n"

    create_table_script = create_table_script.rstrip(',\n') + "\n);\n"

    # Print the table script
    print(create_table_script)
```

The result of the above is probably not going to be exactly what you want, but it gets you started.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Just something to get me started. But I'm getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` at line `table_data[headers[len(table_data)]] = values`

Comment: Nevermind, I just threw in a -1 after `len(table_data)` Thanks for the help